# How do I dual boot two Ubuntu 22.04 LTS installations?

Tags: dual-boot, 22.04, lts

I can dual-boot Linux Mint and Ubuntu. This doesn't seem to work with dual booting Two Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Installations (Both 22.04 LTS).

Any suggestions as to why this does not work and a proposed solution?

Comment: The title say 20.04 and the question only talks about 22.04 please edit as needed to clear this up.

Comment: No none of us will. You can install and use 10 Ubuntu 20.04's and/or 22.04's if you wanted. All you need is disk space.

Comment: "This doesn't seem to work with dual booting two ubuntu 22.04 lts (same versions)"... And why on earth would you want  2 installations of the same Ubuntu version? You have to be trolling.

Comment: @PaulBenson   Two installations can be useful, one you can play/mess around with and keep the other for work, find help when you mess up too much.

Comment: Can you tell us what is not working?  It should work, but just saying not working does not tell us much.

Comment: It's somewhat tedious, and lengthy process, but if you are willing to do it, then sure. I will post an answer. but why do you want to do that?

Comment: The reason why two ubuntu's don't seem to work (my observation) is that grub doesn't show it (even after grub-update). It can only find one ubuntu. As soon as I install linux mint it finds ubuntu and linux mint.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.